CORS error in ASP.NET Web API and React app hosted on IIS
I'm developing an application with ASP.NET Web API as the backend and React as the frontend, both hosted on IIS. When I try to access the backend from a client PC using Firefox, I encounter the following CORS error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://10.1.221.43:44312/api/service/LoadDtatabydate. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).” The application works properly when accessed from the server itself. How can I resolve this CORS issue?

Try to add the below code in your web.config file:
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>


Changed the codes and restarted IIS, but it's still not working. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://10.1.221.43:44312/api/service/LoadDtatabydate. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

@uploadev could you show where you have added this code in frontend or backend ?

@uploadev could you also try  adding this code <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">       <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>

@uploadev also refer this document to enable in the web api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I have enabled CORS in the backend and added the necessary configurations to the Web.Config file. The backend is developed using ASP.NET Web API.

@uploadev add this code in your api var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";      var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);  builder.Services.AddCors(options =>   {       options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,                         policy  =>                         {                             policy.WithOrigins("your react url"); //                        });   }); 
